# How can I output a list of values for a custom field, and posts with those values?

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field ('source'), which accepts various values (author names), assigned per-post through a custom metabox.

I want to produce a front-end page which lists each author (alphabetically a-z), and nested beneath each are the linked-titles of posts attributed to that author.

Example:

**Author #1**
Post title 1
Post title 2
Post title 3

**Author #2**
 Post title 1
 Post title 2

**Author #3**
Post title 1
Post title 2
Post title 3

Despite searching, I've thus-far no idea where to even begin with this.